# generating graph with unequal intervals using QWT in Qt

Tags: qwt

I am able to generate the graph with equal intervals on both the axis using **QWT**.

Example: If i give the range as *100 to 1* and set the tickstep as 10, the tick label is *100 90 80 70 60* ....

But I need to generate dynamically with unequal intervals.

**Expected output:**

*Example:* In x-axis I have to get the tick label as *100 50 40 30 10 9 8* ...

In y-axis I need the tick label as *0.1 ,0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 99999, 99999*

space and number interval should not be same. How can we generate graph with unequal intervals in x and y axis using **QWT**.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ticks manually using QwtPlot::setAxisScaleDiv().